# Reactjs can't return jsx within pure functional component 'ParseError: Unexpected token'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, babeljs

I'm learning how to use Reactjs through a Net tuts series called 'Modern Web Apps with React and Redux'. Right now we're just covering the basics of react components, yet, for whatever reason, I can never return jsx from a pure function, use classes, or any other various methods of creating components I've found online.

Seeing as I've already tried many different methods of creating a component, my guess is that the error resides somewhere within how I use watchify and babelify.

Here is the error I get:

```
/home/michael/Documents/Web Dev/flaschard-app/src/app.js:33
return (<div className="app">
     ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js:

```
const cards = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CARD':
            let newCard = Object.assign({}, action.data, {
                score: 1,
                id: +new Date
            });

            return state.concat([newCard]);

        default:
            return state || [];
    };
};

const store = Redux.createStore(Redux.combineReducers({
    cards
}));

// store.subscribe(() => {
//  console.log(store.getState());
// });
//
// store.dispatch({
//  type: 'ADD_CARD',
//  data: {
//      front: 'front',
//      back: 'back'
//  }
// });

const App = (props) => {
    return (<div className="app">
        <h1>Hello React!</h1>
        </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "flaschard-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tern-react": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "watchify src/app.js -o public/bundle.js -t [babelify --presets [react es2015]]",
    "server": "cd public; live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

## Thank you!

Comment: try name your file: `app.jsx`

Comment: No luck, same error occurs

Comment: You need to add `import React from 'react';` at the top of app.js. If it doesn't help, show your webpack.config.js and .babelrc

Comment: No .babelrc and I'm not using webpack. Also, the import didn't fix anything. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: not getting this, `i am not using webpack`, if u dont use the webpack then how ur code will convert into `javascript` from `jsx`, n who will create the `bundle.js` file ?? u need to run `webpack` to create `bundle` n `jsx` conversion.

Comment: I'm using the npm tools `watchify` and `babelify`. It's in my package.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is wrong `watchify` command syntax. You should separate square brackets in the command just like in [examples](https://github.com/babel/babelify#usage) to make `babelify` work:

```
watchify src/app.js -o public/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 ] ]
```

Comment: Can you please explain @MichaelLeCompte the reason behing separating brackets.

Comment: I'm not precisely sure why this caused a change in running the program. You would think that the program would error if it had an issue parsing the argument input, but it does not. Nonetheless, for some reason not separating the brackets causes the watchify to incorrectly run. I believe that it's because it can't correctly understand that it's supposed to also run babelify every file change, thus the JavaScript is not being transformed properly by babelify, and watchify does not understand the JavaScript it's being fed. Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, I've found the reason. `watchify` (which is essentially a plugin launcher for `browserify`) uses a tiny library [subarg](https://github.com/substack/subarg) to parse nested contexts with brackets, like in the case above. It has several cases of unexpected behavior. First, it completely ignores unclosed contexts. Second, if you have double brackets, they would be interpreted as closing context only once. So, **double brackets are not supported**.

Comment: As an example, `watchify src/app.js -o public/bundle.js -t [babelify --presets [react es2015 ] ]` works nice as well.  `watchify src/app.js -o public/bundle.js -t [ launchNuclearMissles --targets [ london new-york tokyo ]]` works as if there is nothing after `-t` argument without causing an error.

Comment: this vodoo magic worked for me too. Need to rebuild of course.